# WSL separate Bash and Ubuntu applications and unable to open "Ubuntu" one at directory where I currently am in file explorer

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So I'm trying to make WSL work as intended but I'm having some issues. First I don't understand why there are separate applications for Bash (comes as soon as you enable WSL) and for Ubuntu (distro you can download from Microsoft Store).

I've set up Ubuntu one to have colors and look of how I want it and it also has an icon which is really nice. The "Bash.exe" one has no icon but it does have one feature that I can't seem to figure out how to set on "Ubuntu" one - I can right click and open it wherever I want and it automatically starts at the location that I had in file explorer. I can do the same for "Ubuntu" one (just changing the file to open in regedit) but it won't open at directory I'm currently at.

I'm wondering if there's a way to do that. If there is none I'm alternatively wondering if there's a way to add icon and change colors of the "bash" one as it seems usual methods of adding icons aren't working for WSL.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are accessing the same 'version' of ubuntu with different users/environments/shells. You can prove (or disprove this) by saving a file in the home dir and looking at it in both 'different' installations.

example:
first open:

```
C:\Windows\System32\bash.exe
```

and run:

```
damo@laptop:~$ cd ~
damo@laptop:~$ pwd
/home/damo
damo@laptop:~$ touch foobar.txt
damo@laptop:~$ ls
foobar.txt
damo@laptop:~$
```

then to compare open: (this is in my case, yours will differ, i changed the default install dir)

```
C:\_distros\Ubuntu\ubuntu1804.exe
```

and run the commands:

```
➜  ~ cd ~
➜  ~ pwd
/home/damo
➜  ~ ls
foobar.txt
➜  ~
```

For me this difference is that i have installed zsh as the default shell so there are many differences in the two shells try running `echo $0` which will show your shell.

I'm interested to know the outcome of this as for as far as i know simply 'enabling' wsl will not 'install' anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try option `ubuntu1804.exe run`.

Explanation:

My `ubuntu1804.exe` is in `C:\Users\walter\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps`.
When I open a windows `CMD` shell (not `bash`!), I can descend to the folder with `ubuntu1804.exe` and check the options with `/?`:

```
C:\Users\walter\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps>ubuntu1804.exe /?
Launches or configures a Linux distribution.

Usage:
    <no args>
        Launches the user's default shell in the user's home directory.

    install [--root]
        Install the distribuiton and do not launch the shell when complete.
          --root
              Do not create a user account and leave the default user set to root.

    run <command line>
        Run the provided command line in the current working directory. If no
        command line is provided, the default shell is launched.

    config [setting [value]]
        Configure settings for this distribution.
        Settings:
          --default-user <username>
              Sets the default user to <username>. This must be an existing user.

    help
        Print usage information.
```

The option `run` seems to be what you want.
I tested it from the directory `C:\Users` (my wsl `.bashrc` modifies the prompt)

```
C:\Users>C:\Users\walter\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\ubuntu1804.exe run
walter@wsl:/mnt/c/Users
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Bash.exe is deprecated.
use Wsl.exe instead